# How should i do this animation?

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I need to create an animation inside an app, that looks like the moleskines in the app 
Paper by fiftythree, I am using the iCarousel pod but I need to create an animation that looks like you are turning the page, do you have any ideas, examples or documentation that helps me to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Mark Pospesel's MPTransition.

https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to write your own page-turn animation. One possible approach is to use a UIPageViewController, which does this for you.

Comment: yes, i don't want to write it by myself i just want something that helps me to do it